# React Native Youtube loop certain section of video

Tags: react-native, youtube

I'm attempting to loop a certain section (4 seconds) of a YouTube video on autoplay in React Native, but it just stops playing whenever I reach the end of the loop. I've tried using playlist instead of the videoId, and it will loop, but it will start the video from the beginning. Is there a way to only loop the desired 4 seconds of the video?

```
<YoutubePlayer
       height={.54 * SCREEN_WIDTH}
       videoId='bWX0-NEjyNQ'
       mute={true}
       play={true}
       initialPlayerParams={{
           start: 10,
           end: 14,
           loop: true,
       }}
/>
```